# How to specify nonce value of ERC token transfer?

Tags: go-ethereum

I use the code lines below to set nonce and transfer ERC20 token from account to another:

```
var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
await contract.methods.transfer(destAddress,amount).send({from: myAddress;nonce: count});
.once('Transaction hash', (hash) => { console.log(hash); })
.once('Receipt', (receipt) => { console.log(receipt); });
```

however the nonce value is said undefined as bellow:

```
0x3b20fe7cf7432579e4016e8fdf7565da1d36804fb737ab97608fbe5101348368
{ blockHash:
   '0xb8f68667e9b7dfb6737ecef6ea1d8afd24aaef0e6a84d607758c69ee9aa22ac2',
  blockNumber: 6663,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 36273,
  from: '0x3c46B43e683b5addd7e66b3d1D958854FfB58361',
  gasUsed: 36273,
  logsBloom:
   '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000020000000000001000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000100002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0x9d49B7e597d2476cc0Bca8CEb7DC5Ad983793FbA',
  transactionHash:
   '0x3b20fe7cf7432579e4016e8fdf7565da1d36804fb737ab97608fbe5101348368',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  nonce: undefined,
  gas: undefined,
  events:
   { Transfer:
      { address: '0x9d49B7e597d2476cc0Bca8CEb7DC5Ad983793FbA',
        blockNumber: 6663,
        transactionHash:
         '0x3b20fe7cf7432579e4016e8fdf7565da1d36804fb737ab97608fbe5101348368',
        transactionIndex: 0,
        blockHash:
         '0xb8f68667e9b7dfb6737ecef6ea1d8afd24aaef0e6a84d607758c69ee9aa22ac2',
        logIndex: 0,
        removed: false,
        id:
         'log_0x210f90b5c68e9bc9fe8637920340676b94c1ee6db3c33cb6baa242b16c997035',
        returnValues: [Object],
        event: 'Transfer',
        signature:
         '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
        raw: [Object] } } }
```

So what's the correct way to set nonce number for token transfer?
thanks.

Comment: You should by the least change `{from: myAddress;nonce: count}` to `{from: myAddress,nonce: count}`. I'm not sure about the effect of a semicolon inside an object in Javascript, but I would guess that the object which you are passing contains only the `from` field.

Comment: no effect for printed message like above when modify semicolon to coma.I also check the block info, the nonce for the block is really zero. but when I use "eth.sendTransaction()", the nonce value is positive value, adding one automatically.

Comment: Checked again, in the block info, the nonce is the correct number as set value when transferring token. I would say the info in printed "nonce : undefied"  for console.log(receipt) function should be incorrect.Anyway, the setting of nonce for token transfer takes effect as expectation.Thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 0):

the role of **account nonce** in Ethereum is **as same as the timestamp in Bitcoin**

assume Alice transfer Bob to X ETH twice.

transactions need to be distinguishing.

it is a role of account nonce.

nonce is incremented by every transaction signed by the same account.

---

Also, users **can enter nonce** only to cancel the previous tx in tx pool.

If there are same-nonce txs in the transaction pool, the tx with higher gas price will survive.

Comment: The question wasn't about what a nonce is but about how to use it properly